# IOS, uiviewcontroller.h is locked for editing

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

I've a problem with `XCode`. I'm seraching for a solution for a while now, maybe a few hours, but with no result.

I've to create an outlet of a `UITextView`. When I use control+drag to the controller code and fill in what it asks, I get an popup:

> UIViewController.h is locked for editing and you may not be able to save your changes. Do you want to unlock?

When I click on unlock there will appear another popup that says it's unable to unlock because it seems I don't have the permission to do that.

How and what do i have to change so I will have that permission?

Thanks.

Comment: `sudo chown -R YourUserName projectDir && sudo chmod -R 755 projectDir`

Answer (score 3):

The file `UIViewController.h` is an iOS SDK file and you should not modify it. If you want to do something with the class, subclass it.

Comment: Ok thanks. Do I need to make a subclass of the UIViewController of the textview? In the final result the textview should change deu a selection in a Picker. Sorry for asking maybe the easiest qeustions there are in iOs land :P

Comment: To your question, you subclass UIViewController connect the appropriate outlets (if you're using IB) and modify the textView within you view controller subclass.

Comment: You're 100% right, I am following a tutorial right now. But that stupid problem occured. Maybe they should explain it better in the toturial. Thanks for the help btw :)